# tail from a specific starting word

Tags: linux, tail

I'm trying to get the last lines of a text file starting with the word 'cold'. I don't know which line the first occurrence of the word will be but I want it and every line after it to print. I've tried using `tr` but I can't seem to find a way around needing to know the line.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (in bash)

```sh
wordtail(){
    linenumber=$(grep -n "$1" "$2" | sed 's/:.*//' | tail -1)
    tail +$linenumber "$2"
}

wordtail cold your_file
```

You create a function that does what you want, because the commands themselves do not support it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to find the **last** occurrence of a word, instead of the first, then Ljm Dullaart's answer will read the whole file every time. Here's an alternative that will read from the end of the file until it finds the first instance of the keyword. This is much faster for large files.

```bash
wordtail(){
    linenumber=$(tac "$2" | grep -n "$1" -m 1 | sed 's/:.*//')
    tail -$linenumber "$2"
}

wordtail cold your_file
```

Comment: the OP wants to print from the *first occurrence of the word*, not the last one. And are you sure this is fast and `tac` doesn't read the whole file to revert?

Comment: Ah, that's true. Then you would need to count from the start to find the first occurrence. I will update. I am not 100% sure `tac` doesn't read parts of the whole file, but this is definitely *much* faster for large files. https://gist.github.com/Multihuntr/8e7f2376f878c4fcb7160e49b0b0ba70

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know which line the first occurrence of the word will be but I want it and every line after it to print.

It seems you want to get the **last part of the file** from the *first occurrence of the pattern to the end*. In that case use awk instead

```sh
awk '/cold/ { f = 1 } f' yourfile.txt
```

This will set the flag to true on the first match, which is the first line containing `cold`. If you want to find the first line that starts with `cold` then change the pattern like this

```sh
awk '/^cold/ { f = 1 } f' yourfile.txt
```

This doesn't need to read the file multiple times so it **even works in a pipe**, unlike the other answers

```sh
some 'command' "with" args | awk '/cold/ { f = 1 } f'
some 'command' "with" args | awk '/^cold/ { f = 1 } f'
```

Note that it'll do a case-sentitive match. To match case-insensitively use either of the below

```sh
awk '/cold/i { f = 1 } f' yourfile.txt
awk -v 'IGNORECASE=1' '/cold/ { f = 1 } f' yourfile.txt
awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE = 1} /cold/ { f = 1 } f' yourfile.txt
```

Comment: I believe the OP was asking for the first time "cold" appears at the start of a line. This solution doesn't check this.

Comment: @Multihunter may be that's true, but I doubt that because otherwise the OP would say `Cold` instead of `cold`

Comment: Unless it's csv data or logs or mangled or anything other than perfectly formed long-form prose as plain text. Because they specifically asked for "lines", I read it as something like "there is a csv file, and at some point, the first field becomes 'cold', and I want to read those lines until the end". Regardless, thanks for updating your answer.